# Running VS unit tests crashes IISExpress with code 666

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have a VS2013 solution with three projects inside: A console app, an API project using IIS Express, and a test project. In order to complete the integration tests which are Visual Studio unit tests using RestSharp, I have both an instance of the console app and the API running during testing. However when I debug a test, it will immediately close my API project with:

> The program '[7628] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 666 (0x29a).

I tried running the IIS Express API through the command line using `iisexpress /site:API /trace:i`. However, the service crashes as soon as I debug a test as well. Other developers on my team have also run these tests in the same manner, but without such errors. I strongly suspect it is a local IIS Express or Visual Studio setting issue, rather than the code.

I have not been able to find documentation on what *code 666* means. Please tell me what this error code means if you are familiar with it. Any insight to why this is occurring would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Are your IIS trying to invoke Satan?

Comment: @StriterAlfa, I'm hoping this issue doesn't take a biblical turn :)

Comment: @NikolaiDante, I'm hoping to get some code up soon, but so far smaller ASP.NET Web API 2 project with unit testing seem to work fine locally, even when I update the default tests to use RestSharp. Curious...